# Building 16 bit os - character array not working

Tags: string, gcc, operating-system, pointers, 16-bit

I am building a 16 bit operating system. But character array does not seem to work.

Here is my example kernel code:

```
asm(".code16gcc\n");
void putchar(char);

int main()
{
char *str = "hello";

putchar('A');
if(str[0]== 'h')
    putchar('h');

return 0;
}


void putchar(char val)
{

   asm("movb %0, %%al\n"  
       "movb $0x0E, %%ah\n" 
       "int $0x10\n"
      :
      :"m"(val)
     ) ;
}
```

It prints:

```
A
```

that means putchar function is working properly but

```
 if(str[0]== 'h')
        putchar('h');
```

is not working.

I am compiling it by:

```
gcc -fno-toplevel-reorder -nostdinc -fno-builtin -I./include -c -o ./bin/kernel.o ./source/kernel.c
ld -Ttext=0x9000 -o ./bin/kernel.bin ./bin/kernel.o -e 0x0
```

What should I do?

Comment: How in particular is it failing?  What output or errors are you seeing?

Comment: It is giving output the character 'A'. That is the putchar('A') is working. But the putchar('h') is not working that means the condition in if statement fails. But I initialized str = "hello"; Then what is wrong?

Comment: Could you try to print what is there, do a `putchar(str[0])` to see what you find.  I did not look closely but you want to make sure that the initialization you think you did really worked right.  Then we can diagnose the problems from what we see.

Comment: putchar(str[0]) prints an arrow sign. Its a garbage value I think.

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question, but in your environment I think you have to use -ffreestanding option for GCC.

Answer (score 1):

Your data segment is probably not loaded in to the target. What are you doing after the link with your brand new kernel.bin file, which is in fact an elf file ?